# voltage drop of LC filter in reverse

Tags: electric-circuits, capacitance, inductance

Two questions that are probably really simple to others.

[image]

If we are to measure the voltage drop across the capacitor, the same way the circuit above is usually used as an LC filter, we would get the following expression.

$V_{out}$ = $V_{in} \times \frac{1}{1-\omega^2 L C}$.

I started wondering if it would make sense to use the same relation to predict the voltage drop at the other end. So $V_{out}$ would be our input and we are measuring what's represented as $V_{in}$ in the equation above.

Can someone explain to me what one would measure across the left end, if we input some voltage (dc and ac) across the right end (where it says Vout)

Comment: If you confine yourself to lumped element circuit theory with Kirchhoff's laws then you may not connect an *ideal voltage source* in parallel with an ideal capacitor because it will lead to "infinities" and inconsistent initial conditions. If you allow more practical elements then you will have to allow for a nonzero *series* internal resistance both for the source and for the capacitor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This circuit does not have any load, which, for the reverse direction, would be connected across $V_{in}$. We can say that the load has infinite impedance.

Because of that, no current would flow through the inductor and therefore it could be replaced by a wire.

So, we'll end up with a circuit consisting of just one capacitor, which should be easy to analyze.

Comment: just to be sure, you effectively only have the capacitor and the voltage measured across the capacitor is whatever voltage you input. correct?

Comment: @Blackwidow Yes. And the current is whatever current flows into the capacitor.